# error in logincheck symfony3.*

Tags: symfony, security, authentication

Hi guys I need your help, is not my first login on symfony but I dont really know what I am doing wrong this time, I am getting this error

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("title") on a boolean variable ("").
```

Well the problem is when I try to login I dont know why go to PostController, here is my code
Securyty.yml

security:
    providers:
        users:
            entity: { class: AppBundle\Entity\User, property: email }

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    frontend:
        pattern:        ^/*
        provider:       users
        anonymous:      ~
        form_login:
            login_path: user_login
            check_path: user_login_check
        logout:
            path:       user_logout
        remember_me:
            secret:     123
            lifetime:   604800  # 604.800 = 3.600 * 24 * 7 = 1 week
access_control:
        - { path: ^/*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER]
```

my controllers

front

```
   class FrontController extends Controller
        {
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $featured=$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')->findBylimit(3);
    $list_post=$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')->findAll();
    return $this->render('front/homepage/index.html.twig',[
        'featureds'=>$featured,
        'list'=>$list_post,
    ]);
}
```

}

```
  class SecurityController extends Controller
  {
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="user_login")
 */
public function loginAction()
{
    $authUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
    return $this->render('front/homepage/_login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $authUtils->getLastUsername(),
        'error' => $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError(),
    ));
}
/**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="user_login_check")
 */
public function loginCheckAction()
{
}
/**
 * @Route("/logout", name="user_logout")
 */
public function logoutAction()
{
}

public function boxloginAction()
{
    $authUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    return $this->render('front/homepage/_login.html.twig', array(
        'last_username' => $authUtils->getLastUsername(),
        'error' => $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError(),
    ));
}
```

`class PostController extends Controller
{`

```
/**
 *@Route("/{slug}/",name="view_post")
 *
 */
public function singlePostAction(Request $request,$slug){
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $id=$request->get('id');
    $single_post=$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')->findByTitle($slug,$id);
    $coments=$em->getRepository('AppBundle:Post_comment')->findByPost($single_post);

    if($single_post){
        $single_post->setViews($single_post->getViews()+1);
        $em->flush($single_post);
    }

    return $this->render('front/post/_single.html.twig', [
        'single_post'=>$single_post,
        'comments'=>$coments,
    ]);
}

public function postCommentAction(Request $request){
    $comment= new Post_comment();
    $form = $this->createForm(Post_commentType::class, $comment);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isSubmitted()){

    }

    return $this->render('front/post/_comment.html.twig', [
        'form'=>$form->createView(),
    ]);

}
```

}

is this last one is my problem, when i try to login the error is cause go to singlePostAction and i dont know why, this action is just when a user clic a post title on homepage

Comment: Will you please share your `front/homepage/_login.html.twig` ?

Answer (score 1):

because `/{slug}/` is catching other routes !

Comment: thanks I resolve de problem, Sam thanks, I changed the routing post controller to /post/{slug}/